# Closure requires unique access to lambda function

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm learning Rust, and have implemented some simple code to experiment with closures - but am running up against an issue with the borrow-checker that I'm not sure how to resolve.

When compiling the following function

```
fn twice(x:int, f:|int| -> int) -> int {
    f(f(x))
}
```

I get the following error

```
closure requires unique access to `f` but it is already borrowed
```

I'm working through the guide and have a moderate understanding of why the borrow-checker doesn't like this - but I'm unsure how to resolve it.

I can work around it by assigning the results of the first call to a temporary variable first, and then calling `f(..)` again on this. However this feels inelegant.

Is there a cleaner/better way of writing `f(f(x))`, or some way to convince the compiler that this is safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full error message is:

```
<anon>:2:7: 2:8 error: closure requires unique access to `f` but it is already borrowed
<anon>:2     f(f(x))
               ^
<anon>:2:5: 2:6 note: previous borrow of `f` occurs here; the unique capture prevents subsequent moves or borrows of `f` until the borrow ends
<anon>:2     f(f(x))
             ^
<anon>:2:12: 2:12 note: previous borrow ends here
<anon>:2     f(f(x))
                   ^
```

That is, the outer call is, in some sense, reserving `f` and preventing it from being used first. This is very similar to [issue #6268](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/6268), which concerns methods instead of closures.

As you say, using a temporary is a fix, and is the most reasonable fix.

```
fn twice(x:int, f:|int| -> int) -> int {
    let y = f(x);
    f(y)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if this is this intentionally part of the language, or an edge case in the borrow-checker that will we cleaned up at some point?

Comment: This certainly must be fixed.

Comment: @JamesDavies, mainly an edge case (e.g. see the issue I reference).

Answer (score 0):

In modern Rust, the original code compiles as-is:

```
fn twice(x: i32, f: impl Fn(i32) -> i32) -> i32 {
    f(f(x))
}

fn main() {
    twice(42, |i| dbg!(i));
}
```